# Generic collection of generic types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I was wondering what would be the best approach
To solve this:

```
object GetCollection(T1, T2) 
{
    return new T1<T2>;
}
```

Well I know this will not compile but it states my point.
I need to create a collection type based on a generic type passed T1 and it should contain elementy of type T2,

Aby ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you are doing `new T1`, but you ... *need to create a collection type* ... so no really this example is not stating your point. please elaborate a bit more. are you doing some sort of `if-else` on `T1` or if-else on `T2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via reflection. Otherwise, I will recommend using interfaces based on what the list of T1s could be.
Something like this:

```
class GenericContainerOne<T> { }

class GenericContainerTwo<T> { }

class Construct { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GenericContainerOne<Construct> returnObject = (GenericContainerOne<Construct>)GetGenericObject(typeof(GenericContainerOne<>), typeof(Construct));
}

static object GetGenericObject(Type container, Type construct)
{
    Type genericType = container.MakeGenericType(construct);

    return Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
object GetCollection<T1, T2>() where T1 : IEnumerable<T2>, new()
{
    return new T1();
}
```

If you don't know the types at compile time, then you'll need to bind the generic type with reflection. [This Microsoft article may cover your needs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is like this:

```
object GetCollection<T1, T2>() 
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T1).MakeGenericType(typeof(T2)));
}
```